# Default config of tinymceBundle

Tags: symfony, tinymce

I can't seem to set the default configuration for stfalcon's tinymce bundle. I followed the instructions given [here](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle#custom-configurations) to no avail.

This is what I have in my config.yml:

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    theme:
        advanced:
            plugins:
                - "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor"
                - "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen"
                - "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
            image_advtab: true
```

and instead of having the toolbar and plugins displayed for the textarea, I have nothing. Somehow, configuring it as I've done messes with tinymce's initialization. Does someone know where my mistake is?

**Update**

Looking at Firefox's debugger tool, it seems like the bit of code:

```
var settings = (typeof options.theme[theme] != 'undefined')
            ? options.theme[theme]
            : options.theme['simple'];

settings.external_plugins = settings.external_plugins || {};
```

in init.standard.js is what causes the problem. `settings` is undefined in `settings.external_plugins = settings.external_plugins || {};`. I don't know what causes this. Initializing tinymce "manually" works though. I encounter no problem if instead of using the twig command, I simply put this on the html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after tinkering with init.standard.js, I've found the solution. Apparently, you have to pass a data-theme attribute to the textarea you want to tinymceize that corresponds to the theme you intend to have a default configuration for in config.yml. Otherwise, init.standard.js doesn't match your configuration seetings to its `settings` variable.

In my case, the theme configured was `advanced` so I just did this in my form builder:

```
$builder
    // ...
    ->add('text', 'textarea', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class'      => 'tinymce',
            'data-theme' => 'advanced'
            )
        ))
    // ...
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's brief checklist what you have to do:

∙ copy the resources to your web folder `php app/console assets:install`

∙ add this `{{ tinymce_init() }}` at the bottom of your page (in javascripts section)

∙ add tinymce selector to your form attributes:

```
<?php
    $builder->add('yourtext', 'textarea', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'tinymce',
        )
    ));
```

∙ and configure the tinymce selector in your conf:

```
# app/config/config.yml
    stfalcon_tinymce:
        #...
        selector: ".tinymce"
```

Try to check out whether you've done it.

**Update**

Also take a look at web browser console and fix the problems if any.

Comment: I have done all of this before trying. I just redid it to make sure but it doesn't solve the problem. tinymce does work when I don't put anything in config.yml (or just the standard theme)

Comment: @Afunakwa take a look at web console in your browser. Is any problems there?

Comment: It found two: `TypeError: $container.attr(...) is undefined` and `TypeError: settings is undefined`

Comment: Actually, just one. the error relating to the container originates from somewhere else entirely

Comment: @Afunakwa I think you should fix this problems at first.